# Stop words and stemmer in java

Tags: java, nlp, stop-words, porter-stemmer

I'm thinking of putting a stop words in my similarity program and then a stemmer (going for porters 1 or 2 depends on what easiest to implement)

I was wondering that since I read my text from files as whole lines and save them as a long string, so if I got two strings ex.

```
String one = "I decided buy something from the shop.";
String two = "Nevertheless I decidedly bought something from a shop.";
```

Now that I got those strings

Stemming:
Can I just use the stemmer algoritmen directly on it, save it as a String and then continue working on the similarity like I did before implementing the stemmer in the program, like running one.stem(); kind of thing?

Stop word:
How does this work out? O.o
Do I just use; one.replaceall("I", ""); or is there some specific way to use for this proces? I want to keep working with the string and get a string before using the similarity algorithms on it to get the similarity. Wiki doesn't say a lot.

Hope you can help me out! Thanks.

Edit: It is for a school-related project where I'm writing a paper on similarity between different algorithms so I don't think I'm allowed to use lucene or other libraries that does the work for me. Plus I would like to try and understand how it works before I start using the libraries like Lucene and co. Hope it's not too much a bother ^^

Answer (score 11):

If you're not implementing this for academic reasons you should consider using the [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) library. In either case it might be good for reference. It has classes for tokenization, stop word filtering, stemming and similarity. Here's a quick example using Lucene 3.0 to remove stop words and stem an input string:

```
public static String removeStopWordsAndStem(String input) throws IOException {
    Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>();
    stopWords.add("a");
    stopWords.add("I");
    stopWords.add("the");

    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(
            Version.LUCENE_30, new StringReader(input));
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(true, tokenStream, stopWords);
    tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    TermAttribute termAttr = tokenStream.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class);
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(termAttr.term());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which if used on your strings like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String one = "I decided buy something from the shop.";
    String two = "Nevertheless I decidedly bought something from a shop.";
    System.out.println(removeStopWordsAndStem(one));
    System.out.println(removeStopWordsAndStem(two));
}
```

Yields this output:

```
decid bui someth from shop
Nevertheless decidedli bought someth from shop
```

Comment: ahh I think lucene is a nono since it is a school related project.

Comment: Why shouldn't you consider Lucene for academic purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can wrap any stemmer so that you can write something like

```
String stemmedString = stemmer.stemAndRemoveStopwords(inputString, stopWordList);
```

Internally, your stemAndRemoveStopwords would

- place all stopWords in a Map for fast reference
- initialize an empty StringBuilder to holde the output string
- iterate over all words in the input string, and for each word

  - search for it in the stopWordList; if found, continue to top of loop
  - otherwise, stem it using your preferred stemmer, and add it to to the output string
- return the output string

Comment: Wait so what you are saying is that there's already a stopword function in porters stemmer? O.o Sorry, I think I'm not getting it. Could you explain it a little more. I was thinking if that Porter's stemmer already had a function like that or not. Having it would be easier to use it ;)

Comment: @N00 - a stemmer is just an algorithm to trim down words to their stems. It has no notion of stop-words; but removing them is really easy with a simple hashmap: put all your stopwords in the hashmap, and before you stem an input word, if it is in the hashmap, then you can discard it instead of stemming it.

Comment: Yes, seems that I'm making a bigger deal out of it than it is. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deal with the whole text. Just split it, apply your stopword filter and stemming algorithm, then build the string again using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StrinBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text.length());
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
for (String word : words) {
    if (stopwordFilter.check(word)) { // Apply stopword filter.
        word = stemmer.stem(word); // Apply stemming algorithm.
        builder.append(word);
    }
}
text = builder.toString();
```

Comment: @Eser Aygün : Ahh but the problem here is that I'm running levenshtein as one of the algorithms and it's best to work with the text as a whole string on it and not as tokens. That's the reason why I would want to run it on the whole string and then end with a string, I can throw in the similarity machine aka still have a string to compare instead of rewriting it to compare the tokens in the levenshtein algorithm.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then why not just join the tokens using a StringBuilder? It's still easier than dealing with the whole text.

Comment: @Eser Aygün : hmmm...you mean first cut it to token, stopword it, stem it and then build the string again before running levenshtein on it? :o

Comment: @N00programmer Exactly. Why does this scare you?

Comment: @Eser Aygün : lol, no it doesn't scare me. I'm not that old to programming so I don't know that much about it. That the reason I'm asking so much was to be sure that I'm not misunderstanding anything. ;) Oh, one little question: Is there a big difference in Stringbuilder and Stringbuffer? I used Stringbuffer and it does the work but both you and WhiteFang use the other so I'm wondering if it's bad of me to use Stringbuffer cuz I will be using big strings later on too.

Comment: @N00programmer Ok. Sorry :) StringBuffer is synchronized, which means that multiple threads can work on a StringBuffer safely. StringBuilder, on the other hand, is not synchronized, and therefore it is a little bit faster. In your case, StringBuilder would be the right choice.