# Lucene StopFilter and PorterStemmer not found

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to use the code from this question - [Stop words and stemmer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122545/stop-words-and-stemmer-in-java)

My Lucene project is a part of a maven project (https://github.com/tdunning/MiA).

When I try and include the code given in the link above in a folder inside the src/ folder, the build process fails. The maven compiler says that org.apache.lucene.analysis.core does not exist (which is the dependency for StopFilter). Similarly, the dependency for PorterStemmer can't be resolved. I tried to look around in the maven project, but couldn't figure out the lucene version they used. What is the best way to be able to use this code for stemming words through Lucene?

P.S: I'm new to the various java build tools, so sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Edit: I managed to resolve PorterStemmer and decided to filter stop words without lucene, so the project works, but if any one can help me resolve the StopWordFilter dependency, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is [`StopFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html) not `StopWordFilter`.